# No puedo llegar a la acción del controlador desde Kendo

Tags: controller, kendoui, routing

tengo un DropDownListFor de Kendo que llama a una acción de un controlador, pero el navegador me saca un 404

```
   @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.TipoBusqueda)
                                  .DataTextField("Text")
                                  .DataValueField("Value")
                                  .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 100%;" })
                                  .OptionLabel(new { Text = "Seleccione...", Value = "" })                                  
                                  .DataSource(source =>
                                  {
                                      source.Custom().Type("aspnetmvc-ajax")
                                          .Transport(t =>
                                          {
                                              t.Read(r => r.Action("GetListPatologias", "ConsultaController", new { Area = "HL" }));
                                          })
                                          .ServerFiltering(false)
                                          .Schema(s => { s.Data("Data").Total("Total").Errors("Errors"); });

                                  })
                    )
```

Carpeta HL, Controlador Consulta, acción GetListPatologias

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetListPatologias([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
```

Pongo un break point en la primera línea y no llega

¿Qué puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 0):

En la petición al servidor, el nombre del controlador no lleva la palabra `Controller`... no era `ConsultaController`, era solo `Consulta`

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.TipoBusqueda)
                                  .DataTextField("Text")
                                  .DataValueField("Value")
                                  .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 100%;" })
                                  .OptionLabel(new { Text = "Seleccione...", Value = "" })                                  
                                  .DataSource(source =>
                                  {
                                      source.Custom().Type("aspnetmvc-ajax")
                                          .Transport(t =>
                                          {
                                              t.Read(r => r.Action("GetListPatologias", "Consulta", new { Area = "HL" }));
                                          })
                                          .ServerFiltering(false)
                                          .Schema(s => { s.Data("Data").Total("Total").Errors("Errors"); });

                                  })
                    )
```

Comment: Hola, puede que la respuesta sea la más correcta del mundo, pero debes ampliarla y dar más detalles